# Scrollable Stacked Images in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to make stacked images in a page but I need the page with the images to scroll so `position:fixed;` isn't working.

I tried this but it makes the images fixed to the screen not the #content div.

```
<div id="content"><!--I made this scrollable in css-->
    <!--other content here-->
    <div id="imageStack">
        <img id="map" src="bg.png" style="position:fixed;x:0;y:0" /><!--this line and the next will be added in JS-->
        <img id="map" src="top.png" style="position:fixed;x:8;y:6" />
    </div>
    <!--other content here-->
</div>
```

Is it possible to make the images **stack** and **scroll* with out using a canvas?

Comment: An ID must be unique. Use classes instead for `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following css

```
#imageStack {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
    top: 6px;
    left: 8px;
}


.... etc
```

they will display relative to the imageStack element

Comment: I *think* he wants the `#imageStack` to be positioned relative to the `#content` div. To do that, he would only need to add `position:relative` to the content, and use `position:absolute` on the `#imageStack`.

Comment: but isn't he trying to stack the images on top of each other? in which case the images would need to be absolute.